# rails, ruby - Given a Regex - Determine the Match Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given something like:

```
 message.split(/\n.* at.* XXXXXXXX wrote:.*/m).first
```

This works if there is a match, but when there isn't, it just returns all of `message`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you're trying to *count* the number of matches, then you're using the wrong method. `split` is designed to take a string and chop it into bits, but as you've observed, if there aren't any matches, then it returns the whole thing. I think you want to use [`String.scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan) instead:

```
message.scan(/\n.* at.* XXXXXXXX wrote:.*/m).size
```

Comment: Thanks but where does that get the length? IE if any matches were found. I just need to know if a match was found or not.

Comment: You _should_ be able to set a regexp like that (works for me). Sorry, just to check, are you saying you literally _just_ want to know if it matches? (i.e. you're not interested in extracting any of the text?)

Comment: Ahh, sorry, just realised that you're trying to count how many matches you get, not really trying to split the string at all. Editing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well split will return an array.  So you could just check for length > 1

```
m =  message.split(/\n.* at.* XXXXXXXX wrote:.*/m)
if m.length > 1 
   return m.first
else
   return nil 
end
```

Comment: @Doon, sorry just tried it out... it always returns m.first. Ideas?

Comment: Here's what I have:     m = to.split(/@mysite.com.*/)
    if m.length > 1 
       return m.first.strip
    else
       return nil 
    end

Comment: Looks like all m.length is doing is counting characters?

Comment: in your example what is in to?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like you are reading the info in a to field, and trying to get some info there might be better way to get that info.

Comment: and also String.split returns an array, and array.length is # of elements in array (size is alias to length). In your code dealing with the to, you should print m, or at least look at it in irb/rails console. to see what split is returning..